# Grouping of data items based on common property

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid

I have a grid in kendo + angular where i need to display the data based on a group. For example: the response from service would return some thing like this

```
item 0 --> Id 1, Name ABC, Age 20, Dept. XYZ, Date date1
item 1 --> Id 2, Name DEF, Age 90, Dept. LMN, Date date1
item 2 --> Id 3, Name TUV, Age 44, Dept. GHI, Date date2
```

The grid would show, 1st column -> Date; 2nd column -> Name - child column -> Age
It has to be grouped by date. Even though my response has 3 items, i need to combine this based on the common date(in this case there will be 2 records, 1 for date 1 and 1 for date 2). 
I have achieved this using the native foreach and index style of coding. It works fine. 
But am looking for a more elegant way and minimal code.
Any pointers will be very helpful.

Thanks